# Upload a picture with user comment

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to upload a local image to Facebook from my native Android app. I also want the user to be able to add a comment. I have done this:

```
params.putString("caption", "Caption");
params.putString("description", "Description");
params.putString("picture", Utility.HACK_ICON_URL);
params.putString("name", "name");

String filename = <file_path>
byte[] data = null;
Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
data = baos.toByteArray();

params.putByteArray("photo", data);

Utility.mFacebook.dialog(ScoreAlertBox.this, "feed", params, new UpdateStatusListener());
```

I see the dialog box with all the fields - icon, caption, decrption. But the picture I want to upload is not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it states in the android sdk dialog [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/dialog/):

> parameters - String key-value pairs to be passed as URL parameters

You can't pass it a local image, it's basically just a way to invoke the [Feed Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) which only accepts a url as the picture parameter.

What you should do is upload the image along with the post using [requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/request/) (or [async requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/ayncrequest/http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/ayncrequest/)).
Also, if you want to upload an image you'll need to use `me/photos`: [User object Photos connection](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos).